# HTTP links only loading on iframes for a local website

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to make a website and it's just on my hard drive like

> C:\Users\name\Desktop\folder\website.html

and it seems that it only loads iframes that include another local website like 
it or an HTTP website but any HTTPS website won't load...

Example for what works : `<iframe src="http://www.bbc.com"></iframe>`

Example for what doesn't : `<iframe src="https://edition.cnn.com/"></iframe>`

Comment: Please show us some examples that didn't worked for you, so we can figure out why.

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck Done

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? For me it's working.

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck nothing appears on the iframe and chrome's console says :-
Refused to display 'https://edition.cnn.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.cnn.com:* http://*.cnn.com https://*.cnn.io:* http://*.cnn.io:* *.turner.com:* courageousstudio.com".